# Why is my "if" loop running? Is this a problem with me or MSVC

Tags: c++

easy example to replicate:

```
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

bool myvarriable = false;

int lala = 0;

void loop() {
    while (1) {
        if (myvarriable == true) {
            std::string memory = "hi";
            std::string memory2 = "hi_people";
            std::string memory3 = "hi_people_3";
            std::cout << "hi";
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    std::thread r{ loop };

    r.join();
    return 0;
}
```

my varriable is set to false, it is never true, yet I see the word "hi" throughout my console. why? when I run this in an online complier it works fine. Also, I am using visual studio and it only has this issue in release mode, debug mode works as intended.
Also, when I set a breakpoint at `std::string memory = "hi";` it hits, but it still says myvarriable is false. how could the "if" statement run?

Comment: You sure this is your full code, and you didn't just strip it down and remove something important in the process?

Comment: Short answer: an infinite loop with no side effects is UB. Make `myvarriable` an std::atomic or add a way to exit the loop.

Comment: @GabrielStaples yes, this is my full code. I an put this into an empty visual studio project and it run.

Comment: @sbabbi `std::cout << "hi";` has side effects.

Comment: Valid C++ program must be possible to end. This code cannot end in any valid way, so it's UB- anything is allowed

Comment: *debug mode works as intended* -- How did you terminate the program?

Comment: @hyde yes, that's why it's being executed even if `myvarriable` is false. When MSVC analyzes `loop()`, it goes: if `myvarriable` is false => UB, hence `myvarriable` must be `true`, so it is allowed to replace `if (myvarriable == true)` with `if(1)`

Comment: Thank you for all the solutions. I added an atomic and a isRunning varriable to the loop and it acts normally now.

Comment: Side note: `if (myvarriable == true)` should be spelled `if (myvarriable)`.